# RequireJS / XMLHttpRequest issue - TypeError: Cannot find function open in object function localRequire(deps, callback, errback) {...}

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, xmlhttprequest, requirejs, jira-rest-api

I've been trying to get info from JIRA REST API to put it in cells inside a spreadsheet. For this I'm writing a Google script attached to the spreadsheet, so, form what I understand, that makes this "in Browser" stuff.

In my project I currently have a main code script as well as the requirejs script (I read that it would be the way for me to call xmlhttprequest from a browser script).

Please keep in mind I'm not that used to scripting and mostly tried to follow documentations, but I must be missing something because I always get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function open in object function localRequire(deps, callback, errback) {...}.

Here's my function so far:

```
function updateFilters() 
    {
      var Test = destinationSpreadsheet.setActiveSheet(destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Nonsense"));
      var url = "myurl is in there"; //I have a test url in there
      var XMLHttpRequest = require(["xmlhttprequest"], function(xmlhttprequest){});
      var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      myRequest.open('GET', url);
      myRequest.onload = function ()
      {
        console.Log(myRequest.response);
      };
    }
```

I'm confused as to why "open" doesn't work. There seem to be no issue when I comment out the line, but of course if I do that I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for javascript:

```
function updateFilters()
  {
    var url = "myurl is in there"; //I have a test url in there
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.open('GET', url);
    myRequest.onload = function ()
    {
      console.Log(myRequest.response);
    };
  }
```

This line is breaking your code:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require(["xmlhttprequest"], function(xmlhttprequest){});
```

Try this for node.js:

```
function updateFilters()
{
  var url = "myurl is in there"; //I have a test url in there
  const XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
  var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myRequest.open('GET', url);
  myRequest.onload = function ()
  {
    console.Log(myRequest.response);
  };
}
```

Note: you new to install xmlhttprequest with npm or yarn first

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did have it installed via npm, but I don't know if I need to do more for the script to "find" it... For the first solution, I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined.`


And for the second one, I get this (I don't think I use node.js, at least I didn't include anything in the script that mentions it...)  which is the issue I had at first, and why I used the previous structure:

`Error: Module name "xmlhttprequest" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded`

Comment: If you describe your enviroment, I'll may be able to help you

Comment: I tried editing my post to include details on what I'm using, apologies if that's not helpful enough, I don't have much experience with any of the things I'm trying to use .-.